# Is there a way to look at a Trello board as a snapshot in time?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

It seems that after cards are archived, they are removed from the boards they were associated with. I'm hoping that's not the case and that various metadata about the cards are tracked. What I want to be able to check is the state of a list (or board) at a specific timestamp in time.

Comment: This is still not currently possible. What you CAN do is make a copy of the board and label it with the date to look back at it later.

Answer (score 1):

No to "snapshot in time", Your Trello board is always a current version of your items (lists, cards) as they are now.

Your Archived cards are still stored within the board. Once you Archive a card, it is stored in "Archived Items" under the board Menu with all of the other archived cards.

There is no way to go back and see any previous state of your boards.  Always move forward.

Comment: Sure, I know that the Trello board represents what I have now. But it's still useful to look at the sort of progress I did weeks ago, especially since it's easier for me to think about my progress that way.

Comment: The best way to see recent completed items is to leave the completed cards in the Done / Completed list.  Then after 30+ days go ahead and archive them.  Otherwise there are no historic snapshots.   Good Luck!

Comment: To clarify, your answer amounts to saying "No" to the question. "Snapshot" always means a timeline-like functionality - to see what the board had looked like at a certain time in history. That terminology is used everywhere e.g. in Google Docs, for examples.